# How to get orders based on custom attribute value of product?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, sales-order, custom-attributes

I have a Custom attribute name ( product string ) on Product in which i have save a string i want to get those orders which will have that product string of same value.

I will get the product by :

```
$collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setOrder('created_at','desc');
return $collection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the collection in your block file

```
public function getOrderCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create();           
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('your_attribute_code_here', 1);
        $collection->setOrder('created_at','desc');
        return $collection; 
    }
```

now call this collection in your phtml file

Comment: I am getting error 
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'custom_attribute' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table` WHERE (`custom_attribute` = 'test_string') ORDER BY created_at DESC @Chikku

Comment: Actually i want to use order and product collection togather.